# Crontab does not run any job

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, cron

I try to run python script with crontab, but my crontab does not run anything.

I tried to add jobs to `crontab -e`, to `sudo crontab -e` to `sudo nano /etc/crontab`. The script I try to use (file is executable with `chmod +x`, command can be run in terminal):

```
2 * * * 1-5 python3 /home/foo/bar/update.py
```

I wrapped it into shell script (file is executable with `chmod +x`, command can be run in terminal):

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo python3 /home/foo/bar/update.py
```

And run:

```
2 * * * 1-5 sh /home/foo/bar/run_update.sh
```

And then tried just to run sample jobs:

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> /tmp/file
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

Nothing works, no files are created, no output in logs, if I try to pipe to log, nothing happens as well. I am sure, cron service is running, but completely stuck how to make him work.

Comment: You cannot use sudo in crontab. If your scrip needs elevated (root) rights, run it from root's crontab. Also you might need full path for python3. For checking if the commands run at all, check /val/log/syslog; `grep -i cron /var/lig/syslog` there should bee one line for each invocation.

Comment: you mean `sudo grep -i cron /var/log/syslog`

Comment: @SorenA thanks, I did not specified user in crontab, that was on of issues. Now it runs simple commands, but not sh or py files. I added it to `sudo nano /etc/crontab` (is it root's crontab?). `2 * * * * root 1-5 /usr/bin/python3 /home/foo/bar/update.py`, but still no success on runnin this one

Comment: If it runs simple commands, then it works. Further problems are most often script-related: Requiring a display, assuming environment variables that don't exist in cron's environment, and incomplete paths. There are hundreds of cron-won't-run-my-script questions here, and almost all of them are those few common mistakes.

Comment: @user1039698 /etc/crontab is "system-wide crontab" and as you discovered needs a user-name between time-specification and command. The traditional crontab is a per user configuration, edidet with `crontab -e`. The cron files lives in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username> ... and they don't have username in 6's field.

Comment: @yangmandi `sudo`is not needed if you are the first/default user on the system (as I think most users here will be). The default user is in adm group as is /var/log/syslog. But if your user isn't in am group, you are right.

Comment: @Soren A I know but i need to use `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cron` runtime environment is quite different from the GUI runtime environment. Run

```
env | sort; set
```

in each environment, saving the results to a file.

If you arrange your `~/.bashrc` appropriately you can preface your Python script with

```
#!/bin/bash
. $HOME/.bashrc
yourPythonScript
```

to set up your `cron` environment.

Read `man -a crontab;man -a cron`.